# Inconsistent units in modal analysis of vibrating beam

Tags: classical-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, vibrations, structural-beam

(*read the last sentence for the actual question*).

Consider an elastically suspended solid body from a massless cantilever beam

[image: fig1]

The equations of motion of such a system are

$$\begin{bmatrix}m\\
 & J_{c}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{\delta}\\
\ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}+\tfrac{3EI}{\ell^{3}}\begin{bmatrix}4 & -2\ell\\
-2\ell & \tfrac{4}{3}\ell^{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\delta\\
\theta
\end{bmatrix}=0 \tag{1}$$

and with some parametrizations, such as $J_c = \eta\, m \ell^2$ and $\frac{3 E I}{\ell^3} = m \Omega^2$ to have the dimensionless parameter $\eta$ to represent the inertial properties of the body, and $\Omega$ to represent some reference frequency of the system.

The above is re-arranged into

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{\delta}\\
\ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\ddot{x}}+\Omega^{2}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}4 & -2\ell\\
-\frac{2}{\eta\ell} & \frac{4}{3\eta}
\end{bmatrix}}_{A}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\delta\\
\theta
\end{bmatrix}}_{x}=0 \tag{2}$$

where the problem $\ddot{x} + \Omega^2 A \,{x} = 0$ has known solutions using [modal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_analysis).

The theory goes that if $u = {\rm X} x$ where ${\rm X}$ is a matrix of eigenvectors, then $A = {\rm X}^{-1} D {\rm X}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The system $ \ddot{u} + \Omega^2 D u = 0  $ has $n$ independent solution of the form
$$ u_i = U_i \cos(\omega_i t) \tag{3}$$ with $\omega_i^2 = d_i \Omega^2$ and $d_i$ the diagonal elements of $D$.

All this is fine, but when it comes to calculating the matrix ${\rm X}$ I noticed a problem with the units. This is because the solution space $x=\begin{Bmatrix}\delta \\ \theta \end{Bmatrix}$ has the first element in units of length, and the second element with no units.

Specifically, the eigenvalues are $$w=2+\frac{2}{3\eta}\left(1\pm\sqrt{\left(3\eta+1\right)^{2}-3\eta}\right) \tag{4}$$ and the eigenvectors matrix $${\rm X}=\begin{bmatrix}6\ell\eta-6\eta+2-2\sqrt{\left(3\eta+1\right)^{2}-3\eta} & 6\ell\eta-6\eta+2+2\sqrt{\left(3\eta+1\right)^{2}-3\eta}\\
\frac{6}{\ell}+6\eta-2-2\sqrt{\left(3\eta+1\right)^{2}-3\eta} & \frac{6}{\ell}+6\eta-2+2\sqrt{\left(3\eta+1\right)^{2}-3\eta}
\end{bmatrix} \tag{5}$$

**But the units are non-sensical** since $\ell$ has length units and $\eta$ is dimensionless. Terms like $\frac{6}{\ell}+6\eta$ are clearly erroneous here. This is not a problem with calculating ${\rm X}$ as it indeed diagonalizes $A$ and provides a *numeric* solution.

**But how can the above eigenvectors make any physical sense?**

To overcome this solution the DOFs should be chosen such that they have consistent units. If the modified solution was $x^\star = \begin{Bmatrix} \delta \\ \ell \theta \end{Bmatrix}$ then the eigenvectors have consistent units and the solution makes physical sense.

My question here is the numeric solution that is yielded by the inconsistent ${\rm X}$ a valid solution, and how so. Or is there a *requirement* for modal analysis to construct a solution vector $x$ with consistent units only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the following eigenvectors:

$$\mathbf v_1= \left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ {l}^{-1}-1/3\,{\frac {
1}{l\eta}}-1/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {9\,{\eta}^{2}+3\,\eta+1}}{l\eta}}
\end {array} \right] ;
\\
\mathbf v_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ {l}^{-1}-1/3\,{\frac {
1}{l\eta}}+1/3\,{\frac {\sqrt {9\,{\eta}^{2}+3\,\eta+1}}{l\eta}}
\end {array} \right],
$$

where the units are consistent.

---

Those  results are from my own program that I wrote with the symbolic program MAPLE. The corresponding eigenvalues are

$$\mathbf \lambda=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 2\,{\Omega}^{2}+2/3\,{\frac {{\Omega}^{2}}{
\eta}}+2/3\,{\frac {{\Omega}^{2}\sqrt {9\,{\eta}^{2}+3\,\eta+1}}{\eta}
}\\ 2\,{\Omega}^{2}+2/3\,{\frac {{\Omega}^{2}}{\eta}
}-2/3\,{\frac {{\Omega}^{2}\sqrt {9\,{\eta}^{2}+3\,\eta+1}}{\eta}}
\end {array} \right]
$$

and

$$X^{-1}\,A\,X= \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think I understand what you did. First we have the same eigenvalues, so that is good. Next you normalized the deflection component $\delta$ part of the eigenvector into 1,. Whereas I used my own procedure which solved $(A-\lambda 1) \pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$ but treating the $0$ as a variable to be solve for together with $v_2$. **Here is where the problem arises.** Doing math with zeros is dangerous. Thank you.

Comment: Did you checked this equation $X^{-1}\,A\,X= \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$ with your eigen vectors?

Comment: yes I did and it gave the correct diagonal matrix.